# MySQLi multiple prepare statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have checked everywhere thoroughly, and have gone through everything possible to find an answer to this. Besides saying "the code doesn't work" which obviously is not enough, I have yet to find anything that will even come close to this. I'm probably going to get downvotes, but let's see how this goes.

I am learning how to do prepared statements for a search query from the user end, and I have to do it for multiple queries. I have to bind parameters to these multiple queries, and then execute them and use them and receive multiple rows. This is most of my code, and what I currently have is *not* reporting any errors whatsoever. It just returns a blank white page.

I am doing this from a simple test.php file, and those are the results I'm getting.

Now for the code.

```
$prep1 = $test->prepare("SELECT * FROM sb__bans WHERE sb__bans.authid=? ORDER BY sb__bans.bid DESC");
$prep2 = $test->prepare("SELECT * FROM sb__bans AS bans INNER JOIN sb__admins AS admins ON bans.aid = admins.aid WHERE bans.authid=? ORDER BY bans.bid DESC");
$prep3 = $test->prepare("SELECT * FROM sb__bans AS bans INNER JOIN sb__servers AS servers ON bans.sid = servers.sid WHERE bans.authid=? ORDER BY bans.bid DESC");

$search = "steam";

$prep1->bind_param("s", $search);
$prep2->bind_param("s", $search);
$prep3->bind_param("s", $search);

$prep1->execute();
$prep2->execute();
$prep3->execute();

while($row = $prep1->fetch() && $admin = $prep2->fetch() && $sv = $prep3->fetch()) {
echo $row['test'];
echo $admin['test'];
echo $sv['test'];
}
```

The database is initialized above this as `$test = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "test");`

`$search = "steam"` steam would be replaced with the the post variable of course, but for testing reasons I've removed that for now and am testing with just a simple variable.

What seems to be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why 3 queries? You can make it just one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two points:

1. Based on personal experience, you can only have one prepared statement in existence at a time. I suspect this is because the db requires each PS to have a session-unique name, and the PHP layer is passing some common default name rather than generating a unique name for each PS. By comparison, the PostgreSQL driver allows an optional name for each PS, but still allows only one *unnamed* PS to exist. Essentially this means that you must `prepare`, `bind`, `execute` and `fetch` one PS *completely* before you can `prepare` the next PS.
2. You're misusing `mysqli_stmt::fetch()`. `fetch()` returns only **`true`** or **`false`**, and is used to update variables which have previously been bound with `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`. To retrieve values into a `$row` array, you must first call `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` to return a `mysqli_result`, and then call `mysqli_result::fetch_array()`.

Comment: I've sorted them so that one is prepared at a time and then binds the result (since I cannot use get_result because I do not have mysqlnd) and then I use fetch_array, but I am getting this error before it is able to fetch array `PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

Comment: If you're doing `SELECT *` you have to `bind_result()` as many variables as there are columns in the table. You might actually find it easier to do all this using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks. I took your tip and decided to rewrite it to use PDO, and everything seems to work now. The only problem I have left now is that for some reason empty() is not working on a clearly empty array. I'll save that for another question though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Do you have anything useful to add to that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the general question you asked.

There is not a single problem with having multiple queries prepared. While speaking of getting results from a prepared query, there is indeed a problem caused by the result buffering. In order to be able to execute another query, you have to call store_result()/get_result() right after execute.

Regarding the particular problem you have.

1. To get errors [you have to ask PHP for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments/22662582#22662582).
2. There is absolutely no point in making three queries, you have to make just one. If you have a trouble making one, ask another question marking it with mysql tag and bringing your 3 queries along.
3. Even for multiple queries it's just wrong idea to do multiple fetches in a single loop. Fetch your query results one by one.
4. Your mysqli syntax even for a single query is incomplete. You need to re-read your tutorial and practice on a single query first.